# JavaScript Select function Cars-rental

Tags: javascript

```
const carSelector = document.querySelectorAll(".cars-select");
const car = document.querySelectorAll(".car");

carSelector.forEach((selected, index) => {
  selected.addEventListener("click", () => {
    car.forEach((car) => {
      car.classList.remove("show");
    });
    car[index].classList.add("show");
  });
});
```

This is showing all the time first element, doesn't matter on which select i click.
I think that "index" is  == 0; but idk how to change it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that the index variable doesn't work as expected. To fix this, we can use the `function` keyword.

```js
const carSelector = document.querySelectorAll(".cars-select");
const car = document.querySelectorAll(".car");

carSelector.forEach(function(selected, index) {
  selected.addEventListener("click", function() {
    car.forEach((car) => {
      car.classList.remove("show");
    });
    car[index].classList.add("show");
  });
});
```

```css
.car {
  display: none;
}

.car.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="cars-select">Car 1</div>
<div class="cars-select">Car 2</div>
<div class="cars-select">Car 3</div>

<div class="car">Car 1 details...</div>
<div class="car">Car 2 details...</div>
<div class="car">Car 3 details...</div>
```

Comment: It's still the same

Comment: Nope. Click "Run code snippet" . Click Car 1, Car 2, Or Car 3 and it will give the details of the car.